# How to get the selected text, not its position in an AlertDialog with MultiChoiceItems

Tags: android, checkbox, android-alertdialog, multichoiceitems

I implemented the google [example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs?hl=pt-br) about alertDialog with multichoititem, in this class:

```
        @NotNull
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            final boolean[] qtdClassif = new boolean[25];
            ArrayList classifica = new ArrayList<>();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Escolha até 3 categorias").setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.classifBovino, qtdClassif, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                int contador = 0;
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                    contador += isChecked ? 1 : -1; 
                    qtdClassif[which] = isChecked;
                    if(contador > 3){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "+3 category added, unselect someone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        qtdClassif[which] = false;
                        contador --;
                        ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(which, false); 

                    }else{ 
                        classifica.add(which);
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "category: "+String.valueOf(classifica.get(0)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // He return to me the index from R.array.classifBovino, not the text from R.array.classifBovino that was selected.

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No category ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            return builder.create();
        }
    }
```

But, this arraylist classifica just have the "positions" of the selected item, which is not very useful, because we usually want the value that the user selected in text (the value of the field, not its position in the list), what I tried was: `((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView()...` but the methods listed here do not clarify my idea of obtaining the text of the selected fields, and not their position

Comment: You passed the list to the `AlertDialog`. Simply use `which` to get the corresponding item from that list.

Comment: But this method simply returns the value of the list in position, for example: selectedItems.get (0) returns me "4", but I don't want 4, I want the text that is associated with 4, which was passed as R. array. *

Comment: That's not very clear at all. Which `R.array`? There isn't one in your snippet. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I added my fully code, see now, please.

Comment: I don't need index 10, i need the value text from the index 10

Comment: Yeah, basically the same thing as I described above, except you're using a resource array. The easiest thing to do would probably be to get the `String[]` yourself; e.g., `final String[] classifBovino = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.classifBovino);`. Then, inside `onClick()`, the corresponding text is `classifBovino[which]`. (You could also then pass `classifBovino` instead of `R.array.classifBovino` in the `setMultiChoiceItems()` call. It would save a resource lookup, but otherwise it'd be the same thing.)

Comment: Post your comment as answer to me vote on your answer

Comment: I made what you says and `classifica.add(classifBovino[which]);` and works very fine to me <3